# XEP-0060:pubsub item

Tags: ios, xmpp, publish-subscribe

Question 1:How to add read/unread status to an item,i want to know whether my published items be read by others (not use another reply item)

Question 2:How to fetch specified items,for instance,all items which is replied to the specified item

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Pubsub has no concept of read/unread, as the nature of pubsub in general is fire and forget.  The publisher typically doesn't know or care who the subscribers are or what they do with the information.  To accomplish this, you will have to provide a separate mechanism to record the read information that you will have to correlate with the published items.
2. You can fetch specific items by their id.  There is no concept of reply so the second part doesn't fit this scenario.

Pubsub doesn't contain business logic, which seems to be what you are looking for.  You will have to build that yourself.